# How to add an image as a background with customPaint?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have an app for painting using custom paint, and I wanted to add an image in the background so it can be painted over it but unfortunately I can't seem to figure out how to do that,I tried using a stack but every time I do the custom paint will only paint on the container but never on the image for some reason
I would really appreciate any help on this matter
Here's the code :

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_colorpicker/flutter_colorpicker.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class DrawingArea {
  Offset point;
  Paint areaPaint;

  DrawingArea({this.point, this.areaPaint});
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<DrawingArea> points = [];
  Color selectedColor;
  double strokeWidth;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    selectedColor = Colors.black;
    strokeWidth = 2.0;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    void selectColor() {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        child: AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Color Chooser'),
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: BlockPicker(
              pickerColor: selectedColor,
              onColorChanged: (color) {
                this.setState(() {
                  selectedColor = color;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
                child: Text("Close"))
          ],
        ),
      );
    }

    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                    end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    colors: [
                  Color.fromRGBO(138, 35, 135, 1.0),
                  Color.fromRGBO(233, 64, 87, 1.0),
                  Color.fromRGBO(242, 113, 33, 1.0),
                ])),
          ),
          Center(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    width: width * 0.80,
                    height: height * 0.80,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.4),
                            blurRadius: 5.0,
                            spreadRadius: 1.0,
                          )
                        ]),
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onPanDown: (details) {
                        this.setState(() {
                          points.add(DrawingArea(
                              point: details.localPosition,
                              areaPaint: Paint()
                                ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
                                ..isAntiAlias = true
                                ..color = selectedColor
                                ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth));
                        });
                      },
                      onPanUpdate: (details) {
                        this.setState(() {
                          points.add(DrawingArea(
                              point: details.localPosition,
                              areaPaint: Paint()
                                ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
                                ..isAntiAlias = true
                                ..color = selectedColor
                                ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth));
                        });
                      },
                      onPanEnd: (details) {
                        this.setState(() {
                          points.add(null);
                        });
                      },
                      child: SizedBox.expand(
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                          child: CustomPaint(
                            painter: MyCustomPainter(points: points),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: width * 0.80,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))),
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.color_lens,
                            color: selectedColor,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            selectColor();
                          }),

                      Expanded(
                        child: Slider(
                          min: 1.0,
                          max: 5.0,
                          label: "Stroke $strokeWidth",
                          activeColor: selectedColor,
                          value: strokeWidth,
                          onChanged: (double value) {
                            this.setState(() {
                              strokeWidth = value;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),

                      IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.layers_clear,
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            this.setState((){
                              points.clear();
                            });
                          }),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyCustomPainter extends CustomPainter {
  List<DrawingArea> points;

  MyCustomPainter({@required this.points});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint background = Paint()..color = Colors.white;
    Rect rect = Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    canvas.drawRect(rect, background);
    canvas.clipRect(rect);

    for (int x = 0; x < points.length - 1; x++) {
      if (points[x] != null && points[x + 1] != null) {
        canvas.drawLine(points[x].point, points[x + 1].point, points[x].areaPaint);
      } else if (points[x] != null && points[x + 1] == null) {
        canvas.drawPoints(PointMode.points, [points[x].point], points[x].areaPaint);
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(MyCustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate.points != points;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A canvas doesn't understand the `Image` type given by Flutter but instead it works with the `Image` class inside the `dart:ui` package. Start by importing this:

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui show Image;
```

It can be used as argument of `drawImage` inside the `paint` method, like this:

```
class MyCustomPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final ui.Image myBackground;
  const MyCustomPainter(this.myBackground);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {    
    canvas.drawImage(myBackground, Offset.zero, Paint());
  }
}
```

This will set the given image as background of your canvas. If you're wondering how to convert from `Image` to `ui.Image`, look at this simple example which uses  `decodeImageFromList` from `dart:ui`.

```
Future<ui.Image> myBackground = await decodeImageFromList(imageFile.readAsBytes())
```

where `imageFile` is of type `File`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer this is really helpful, but I'm still new to flutter if you can help me showing me how can I use this line of code  Future<ui.Image> myBackground = await decodeImageFromList(imageFile.readAsBytes())

Comment: I cannot because it would be too long to explain. Read here: https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await it has everything you need!

Comment: thank you very much again for your answer, I will definitely check the link that you have provided